# how to use Multithreading With ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency

I have a program that works perfectly, unfortunately I have some calculations that takes a lot of time, some minutes.

My objective is to use multithreading to accelerate the parts that take so much time.

In this example I give the prototype of the part that I should parallelize.

```
public static ArrayList<Object2> createListOfObject2(ArrayList<Object1> mylist) {
    ArrayList<Object2> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    Object2 object2;
    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mylist.size(); j++) {
            object2 = heavyCalcul(mylist, i, j);
            listToReturn.add(object2);
        }
    }
    return listToReturn;
}
private static Object2 heavyCalcul(ArrayList<Object1> mylist, int i, int j) {
    int weight = MyCalculator.getInstance().calcul(mylist.get(i),mylist.get(j));
    Object2 Object2 = new Object2(weight);
    return Object2;
}
```

As you can see the method

```
public static ArrayList<Object2> createListOfObject2(ArrayList<Object1> mylist)
```

gets a list of Object1, and should create another list of object2.

I made two for loops, and each time I create an object2 forming by two object, it should take O(n²) time. For bigger list it takes a long time.

So where should I put the multithreading and which type of list should I use?

The second Problem is that the class MyCalculator is a singleton Class, and I create only one object of it, and in my opinion even using multithreading the real program will not benefit of multithreading.

What are the rules I should follow to use multithreading?

Many Thanks.

Comment: The Order Is Not Important in this phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that your object is a singleton is irrelevant. What matters is shared mutable state. So, if your computation don't mutate shared state,  and every computation is thus independant from the others, you can just use a parallel stream:

```
myList.parallelStream()
      .flatMap(first -> myList.stream().map(second -> MyCalculator.getInstance().calcul(first, second)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I was about to suggest that, but I don't agree that the singleton is irrelevant. If it has internal state that state must be protected and then adding more threads probably won't help or will cause bugs. If it doesn't have internal state (and hopefully there is none as it has been created as a singleton!) it is safe.

Comment: Yes , the probleme is in my Singleton Object , I have Many instance object
 and they will be used by the MyCalculator.getInstance().calcul(mylist.get(i),mylist.get(j)) Method;So what are the option.

Comment: For even singelton object if two different objects are calling the same method, the execution of both will be independent unless they have some shared field. The reason is different threads have different method stack but the fields are stored in memory.

Comment: Also a word of caution before using parallelStream. The no. of threads that parallelStream uses are shared across the jvm i.e they have common thread pool. So it is fine to use the parallelStream for calculations but if your calculations involve network calls then you should avoid it because it will block your threads and the next requests will be in the wait state until these tasks end.

Comment: @zakzak if the computations don't **mutate** shared state, you won't have any problem.

Comment: Thanks For every One , the calcul method change the state of some variable instance of my singleton Object , so In my opinion the solution is not using a singleton Object.