# how to parallelize a java program with Stream Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, java-8

Hell Everyone ,

I have created a simplified program to show you what i'm willing to do .
The idea is to create An Edge Between Every Vertex.

The Class **Vertex** :

```
public class Vertex {
    private String sequence = new String();

    public Vertex() {
    }

    public Vertex(String seq) {
        this.sequence = seq;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.sequence.toString();
    }
}
```

The Class **Edge** :

```
public class Edge {

    private Vertex source;
    private Vertex destination;
    private int weight;

    public Edge() {

    }

    public Edge(Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.weight = weight;

    }
}
```

**The Calling Program** :

```
public class Example {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            ArrayList <Vertex> listOfVertex = new ArrayList<>();
            listOfVertex.add(new Vertex("One"));
            listOfVertex.add(new Vertex("Two"));
            listOfVertex.add(new Vertex("Three"));

            ArrayList <Edge> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (i==j)
                        continue;
                    int weight = new Random().nextInt();
                    Edge edge = new Edge(listOfVertex.get(i), listOfVertex.get(j),weight);
                    listOfEdges.add(edge);
                }
            }
      }
}
```

Normally in  this Step The List Of Edges should have

- Edge 1 : one Two
- Edge 2 : one Three
- Edge 3 : Two One
- Edge 4 : Two Three
- Edge 5 : Three One
- Edge 6 : Three Two

How can use Java Stream to use multithreading?
I searched throughout the day to understand the syntax of Java 8 for stream but it's very difficult.

Comment: "How can use Java Stream to use multithreading?" - to do what ?

Comment: To complete the two for loop quicly , because 1- in my real program i'm dealing with a big number of vertices  and 2 - the construction of the Edge took a long time to complete( heavy Calcul).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no reason to use multi-threading here. If you had hundreds of vertices, maybe. But anyway:

```
List<Edge> edges = listOfVertex.parallelStream()
    .flatMap(v1 -> listOfVertex.stream()
                               .filter(v2 -> v2 != v1)
                               .map(v2 -> createEdge(v1, v2)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Many thanks For your Awnser , it's only a simplified program to explain the problem . If I put My real program , no one Will Read it.Another question what do you mean by : createEdge(v1, v2) , is it a method that return An Edge?

Comment: Yes. It creates an edge between v1 and v2 and returns it.

Comment: Yes , Ok , just to add something apart some hundred of vertices The Method createEdge (v1,v2) Take along time to return an Edge ,(some Calculation).

Comment: I just realized you already asked the same question a few hours ago, and I already gave you this exact answer. Why don't you read the original answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618095/571407

Comment: "There's really no reason to use multi-threading here" - totally agree! I'm not sure there'll be any performance gain by parallelizing it even for thousands of nodes - this is something that should be benchmarked.

Comment: @JB Nizet I couldn't understand your answer .

Comment: Then ask for clarification using a comment. Don't just create a new question asking for the same thing. What don't you understand? Have you read the javadoc of the methods involved (filter, map, flatMap)?

Comment: the problem in the earlier anwser ther was no Object Creation .i tried to check some tutorial to understand the syntax but i could not find something clear for my program .anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Many thanks For Everyone who took time to help me.I tested The multi-threaded program on my Ryzen 1700 (8 cores) and the result : the sequential program took up tp 7 min to complete , and the multithreaded program took 47 second .the difference is huge.